# npm not intall this error will show contantly

Tags: npm, npm-install

PS C:\Users\abhis\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\BuzzTalkk> npm i
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\abhis\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\BuzzTalkk/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\abhis\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\BuzzTalkk\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-19T11_26_52_128Z-debug-0.log

why npm not install this error will show